# how to enable autoscrolling in perfect-scrollbar with angular 4?

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

documentation is not being very helpful here. I want to use the perfect scroll-bar in my application so that I bypass issues of compatibility with all browsers. I initialized my code exactly as described here https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/tree/4.x.x/ . 
This is what I did in my html

`<perfect-scrollbar id="chat" [config]="config">
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages">
      {{messages}}
  <li>
</perfect-scrollbar>`

now for each new message I want the container to autoscroll to the latest message. Reading further the documentation I found that there'are directives to call events. that is described at the end of the document I linked earlier. So my approach has been the following in the same component:

```
import {PerfectScrollbarComponent } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
...

constructor(private scrollbar:PerfectScrollbarComponent) { }
...

  ngDoCheck() {
    var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
    this.scrollbar.directiveRef.scrollToBottom(chat.scrollHeight);
  }
```

This gives me an error because it's expecting PerfectScrollbarComponent to be a provider. After I do that, I get another error No provider for ElementRef!.

I am loosing my sleep over this. Can anyone suggest a suggestion on how to implement autoscrolling with perfectscrollbar in angular 4? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

I also spent a lot of time on this and solved this problem as follows:

HTML:

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="window__list">
  ...
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Component:

```
...
import { PerfectScrollbarComponent } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

export class ChatWindowComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
   // Linking to component that using perfect-scrollbar
   @ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarComponent) public directiveScroll: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
   ...
   constructor() { }
   ...
   toBottom(): void {
     if (isUndefined(this.directiveScroll)) return;
     this.directiveScroll.directiveRef.scrollToBottom(0, 100)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PerfectScrollbarComponent is a component as the name suggests, so instead of injecting it, you need to get a reference to it using @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarComponent)
scrollbar?: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
```

Assuming the latest message appear at the bottom of the list, you can use scrollToBottom method available on the directiveRef

```
this.scrollbar.directiveRef.scrollToBottom(0, 500);  // 500ms is the speed
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending so much time I solved my problem using perfect-scrollbar directive.

My problem was to add the new message in the database then scroll to new message. Tried so many methods but

> setTimeout() solved my problem

Sharing the code below

HTML:

```
<perfect-scrollbar>
   <div class="msg-body" [perfectScrollbar] #psBottom="ngxPerfectScrollbar">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let msg of messages">
         <div class="nk-reply-item">
            {{msg.content}}
         </div>
      </ng-container>
   </div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { PerfectScrollbarDirective } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('psBottom') psBottom: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
   messages = []
   constructor() {}

   addMessage(newMsg) {
      // request to backend or simply push the new msg to messages array
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.psBottom.scrollToBottom(0, 500);
      }, 100);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

PS is not a component in my solution, 
All of these solutions didn't work for me. I've fixed like below

```
scrollUp(): void {
  const container = document.querySelector('.main-panel');
  container.scrollTop = 0;
}
```